# XAMMP Wordpress installation can't find pictures/files

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I've cloned my website to xampp for a local version. My WordPress site is located in C:/xampp/htdocs/my-website.

I've also cloned my database to local and changed the urls from the web to http://localhost/my-website.

I've made a .htaccess file and already set xampp overwrite all in httpd.conf that the file won't be ignore.

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my-website/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /my-website/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I can see my website with http://localhost/my-website but all my .js, .css, .png etc. files can't be found. I looked in network analystic from Firefox and the links are not complete.

This is the wrong link:

```html
http://localhost/wp-content/themes/storefront/startseite.js
```

But it should look like this:

```html
http://localhost/my-website/wp-content/themes/storefront/startseite.js
```

I've searched a lot in google but can't find a solution. Hope you know a answer.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is there someone who know an answer?

Answer (score 0):

> changed the urls from the web to http://localhost/my-website....

How did you do that? In wp_options? Or Appearance>>General Settings?

You should use [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to change all URLs in the database options and in post/page content. That tool will correctly change all URLs and it also correctly deals with serialized data in the database.

And, after you make a directory or folder move of a WordPress site, resave permalinks in Settings>permalinks. That will write the correct permalinks to .htaccess.

Also see [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: I've did this with the Search and Replace Tool in my DB and general settings too. I also resaved my permalinks. But the url is still wrong. In my php files I examply write: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/storefront/styleswitcher.js"></script>` but the output on my website is `http://localhost/wp-content/themes/storefront/styleswitcher.js` but it should looks like `http://localhost/my-website/wp-content/themes/storefront/styleswitcher.js`

Comment: Your permalink block in .htaccess may not be correct. Best thing to do is resave permalinks from the WP backend so WP can write them correctly.

Comment: But without the htaccess file with my entry from the top of the question I can't open the backend because xampp don't make the redirect to my website without it

Comment: I tryed to go to wp-admin with my old htaccess. Than deleted the content and saved the permanlinks. Wordpress wrote a new htaccess with the exact same entry and the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I have to make a virtual host for my site. Here are the 4 steps you have to do:

1. Go to C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf and make two new hosts. First set up a localhost so that when you want to call another folder which is no virtual host work:

```html
#localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost> 
#My Website
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/my-website" #your path to your installation
  ServerName my-website.dev #Change my-website to your wish name/url
  ServerAlias my-website.dev #Change my-website to your wish name/url
</VirtualHost>
```

2. Go to the Windows hosts file and add this:

```html
 127.0.0.1  my-website.dev
```

3. Go to your Wordpress .htaccess file and paste this into it:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

You have to save all files and restart your Apache and MySQL Server

4. Now you have to change all Worpdress url's in your database to `http://my.website.dev`. To make this step easy you've to download the Database Search and Replace Script in PHP from `https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/`. Unzip this and paste the folder `Search-Replace-DB-master` in `C:/XAMPP/htdocs`.
   Open your browser and go to this url: `http://localhost/Search-Replace-DB-master/`. Now enter your database informations in the database section (db-name, user, passwort). Go to the top and enter in the `replace` field your old url (in my situation: `https://my-website-old-url.com`) and in the field after `with` your new url (in this situation: `http://my-website.dev`).

Now click on live run in the middle of the page and all of your old urls will replaced with the new one.

Finaly go to the browser and enter your new url: my-website.dev

Thats it! Hope I can help someone with this.